# Graph Api multifiltering to get user with last log in last 30 days

Tags: powershell, graph, microsoft-graph-api

i'm trying to build a request with graph api to get all user enabled not logged in the last 30days. With:

```
$URL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?`$filter=signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime le 2023-12-21T00:00:00Z"
```

i'm able to get all user not logged before 2023-12-21. I need to filter further the list to exclude user with specific field but it is not working:

```
companyName ne 'mycompany' and department ne 'mydepartment' and accountEnabled eq true

$URL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?`$filter=signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime le 2023-12-21T00:00:00Z and companyName ne 'mycompany' and department ne 'mydepartment' and accountEnabled eq true&`$select=userPrincipalName,signInActivity"
```

With follow url i can get all user enabled excluding my company and department.

```
$URL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?`$count=true&`$top=999&ConsistencyLevel=eventual&`$filter=companyName ne 'mycompany' and department ne 'mydepartment' and accountEnabled eq true&`$select=userPrincipalName,signInActivity"
```

but not user not logged in the last 30 days. I tried to add:

```
$URL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?`$count=true&`$top=999&ConsistencyLevel=eventual&`$filter=companyName ne 'mycompany' and department ne 'mydepartment' and accountEnabled eq true&`$select=userPrincipalName,signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime le 2023-12-21T00:00:00Z"
```

but it is not working. There is a way to fix it?

Thankss

Comment: ConsistencyLevel=eventual goes in the headers not in the URI for reference. You can filter for `SignInActivity` as you're doing then filtering on your side for the rest.

Comment: I see some example with consistencylevel in uri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#:%7E:text=Known%20issue.-,signInActivity,-signInActivity), when filtering by `signInActivity`, it can't be combined with any other filterable properties.

Only solution for now is to apply filter for `companyName`, `department` and `accountEnabled` on the client.

Comment: Perfect in that way work but i got all user. Is not possible to add ?select or something else to Say give me user logged before 30day?